# Agenda con clases Python

Tags: python, poo

he estado practicando unos programas en Python y me quedé congelado específicamente en este. Quería saber como podría implementar una actualización de contactos (nombre, teléfono y email) con listas y clases. Al principio lo encontré sencillo por las demás opciones pero después no pude avanzar. Quería saber cómo podía actualizar los contactos (nombre, teléfono, email) almacenados en la lista, es la opción 4 del programa. Quería saber cómo crear la opción de poder actualizar un contacto (nombre, teléfono, email) de la lista, lo he intentado de varias forma y no logro hacerlo.

Lo que llevo del programa es lo siguiente:

```py
class Usuario:

    def __init__(self, nombre, telefono, email):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.email = email

    def __str__(self):
        cadena = f'\n Nombre = {self.nombre}\n'
        cadena = cadena + f' Teléfono = +{self.telefono}\n'
        cadena = cadena + f' Email = {self.email}'
        return cadena

class Agenda:

    def __init__(self):
        self.contactos = []

    def añadirContacto(self, contacto):
        self.contactos.append(contacto)

    def mostrarContacto(self, contacto):
        for contacto in self.contactos:
            print(contacto)

    def buscarContacto(self, nombre):
        for contacto in self.contactos:
            if contacto.nombre == nombre:
                print(contacto)

    def actualizarContacto(self):
        

agenda = Agenda()

def nuevoContacto():

    nombre = input('Ingrese su nombre: ')
    telefono = input('Ingrese su telefono: ')
    email = input('Ingrese su email: ')
    return Usuario(nombre, telefono, email)

def buscador():

    global agenda
    nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre a buscar: ')
    return agenda.buscarContacto(nombre)

def menu():

    global agenda
    opcion = 0
    print(' Agenda de contactos')
    while opcion != 5:
        print('\n1) Añadir contacto')
        print('2) Lista de contactos')
        print('3) Buscar contacto')
        print('4) Actualizar contacto')
        print('5) Cerrar agenda')
        opcion = int(input('\nIngrese una opción: '))

        if opcion == 1:
            contacto = nuevoContacto()
            agenda.añadirContacto(contacto)
            print(contacto)

        elif opcion == 2:
            agenda.mostrarContacto(contacto)

        elif opcion == 3:
            buscador()

        elif opcion == 4:

menu()
```

Comment: Para actualizar un contacto debes de buscar el contacto y saber que atributos vas a actualizar.

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta ?

Comment: Hola, disculpa no me deja actualizar. La pregunta es: Quería saber cómo crear la opción de poder actualizar un contacto (nombre, teléfono, email) de la lista, lo he intentado de varias forma y no logro hacerlo. Lo intente cambiando como tal el nombre, teléfono y email por nuevos valores dados por el usuario. Pero al imprimir los contactos, estos no se actualizan.

Comment: La complejidad del problema dependerá de qué tan bien diseñada está la estructura donde tienes guardados los datos. Sugiero un diccionario con formato: `data = {'id1' : {'nom':'Juan Perez', 'tel':'1234', 'eml':'correo@dom.com'}, 'id2':{...}, ... etc}`. Para editar solicitas el `id` del contacto y modificas los atributos deseados, por ejemplo, para el correo: `data[id]['eml'] = nuevo_correo`